# Function for getting today's date?

Tags: daml

I am creating a 'choice' inside a contract template that requires checking today's date.  My DAML code is as follows:

```
controller dealer can
      Add_Car : CarId
        with
            startCoverage: Date

        do
          -- Check for a legal start date
          assert (
            startCoverage > *today* --should check that its not before today
            )
          create this with date_vehicle_added = startCoverage
```

What is the name of the function I can use to get the current date?  It needs to go where it says "`*today*`".

Answer (score 3):

**tldr:** Use `getTime : Update Time` and `toDateUTC : Time -> Date`,
but be aware of the pitfalls.  Preferably, use the Notarized Date
pattern if this is possible.

#### Modeling Date/Time Implicitly

Modeling date and time is always a subtle problem, doubly so when
dealing with a deterministic, distributed system such as a digital
ledger. DAML provides a primitive function `getTime` which will return
the "Ledger Effective Time" (`LET`), which the ledger model guarantees will be
a monotonically increasing time value (in milliseconds) that is
constrained to within a ledger defined delta of wall-clock UTC time.
This can be converted to a UTC Date using the `toDateUTC` function in
`DA.Date`. This is the straight-line answer to your question, but has
a couple of caveats.

1. This Time and Date are in UTC, you will have to explicitly model
   how this corresponds to local-time. As DAML is a deterministic,
   distributed system, there is no local time as any given transaction
   must be deterministically executed across multiple timezones.
2. Gratuitous use of Date/Time comparisons can lead to contracts being
   implicitly stalled due to the passage of time. If a choice is guarded
   by a check against wall-clock time, this can mean that any delay in
   your application processing an exercise can result in the choice
   becoming invalid. Making sure you handle this case properly in your
   application code is a subtle issue——and as this is an implicit
   parameter to your choice, there is no operational intervention
   possible to avoid the problem even if you have advanced warning.
3. Integration testing of your model and application becomes
   non-deterministic and non-repeatable in the presence of explicit time
   comparisons. While you can write repeatable `Scenario` tests for your
   model, as you have explicit control of `LET` there, this will not
   exercise your off-ledger application.

#### Modeling Date/Time Explicitly

An alternative is the Notarized Date Pattern. Here, the signatories to
a contract agree on a trusted party to notarize the current date. This
notarization takes the form of a `CurrentDate` contract on the ledger.
This contract has the Notary as the signatory, and generally has a
single consuming choice, controlled by the Notary, to advance the
date.

If you use this approach, your `Add_Car` choice would take an extra
parameter `currentDate : ContractId CurrentDate`, which you can think
of as the controller providing evidence or a proof that the agreed
Notary has attested to the current date for the purposes of this
contract. This resolves the issues with the implicit time model thus:

1. As Date is now explicit on the ledger timezones become explicit in
   the progress of the `CurrentDate` contract.
2. While a contract can still be stalled if the Notary advances the
   current date contract, the explicit nature of Date management means
   that a) Any exercise sequenced ahead of the Notary date update will be
   processed successfully; which means, b) There is now an avenue for
   operational intervention where you have advanced warning that
   processing for a given day has fallen behind schedule — assuming such
   intervention is anticipated and permitted by the Notary agreement.
3. Because the operation of your system is once again a pure function of the contents of the ledger, the behaviour of the larger application becomes deterministic and repeatable. This massively reduces the effort required
   for maintenance, testing, and debugging.

For these reasons I would recommend using the Notarized Date pattern where
this is possible, reserving implicit Date handling for those cases where
there really isn't an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Before your `assert`, you can [bind the result of the `getTime` function](https://docs.daml.com/daml/reference/updates.html#gettime). Then I suggest converting `startCoverage` to a `Time`, by means of the `toGregorian` and `datetime` [functions in DA.Date](https://docs.daml.com/daml/stdlib/base.html).

You may not have enough information to do this correctly with your sample code; `Date` is a "local date", expected to be interpreted relative to some timezone, whereas `Time` is an absolute UNIX epoch offset. It's for that reason that there are so many caveats to `toDateUTC` listed in the manual and that I recommend avoiding that function.

Moreover, please keep in mind that only "ledger effective time" is available, which is not quite the same thing as "current time". Sure, for the purposes of the live exercise of `Add_Car`, `getTime`'s result will correspond to the current time. However, transactions are necessarily replayable (for validation or other reasons), and for those executions `getTime` will produce what it originally did on exercise.  You cannot use `getTime` to determine the amount of wall-clock time DAML took to execute some code, and that implies that even during live exercise ledger effective time doesn't correspond *precisely* to wall-clock. When you run [test scenarios](https://docs.daml.com/daml/testing-scenarios.html), the time starts at UNIX epoch and can be advanced manually in your scenario as your test requires; in fact I can recommend using `pass` or `passToDate` to test the very contract you're writing.